# SystemVerilog Interface array with different parameters

Tags: arrays, interface, system-verilog

I've got a parametrized interface with clock input. For example :

```
interface itf # (PARAM1 = 16, PARAM2 = 8)(input logic clk);
```

This interface has a modport called "slave".

My module takes an array of this interface as an input (modport "slave").

```
module MyModule #(NB_ITFS = 4)(... itf.slave itfs[NB_ITFS]...);
```

In a testbench module for `MyModule`, I would like a generic code that is able to test different values of `NB_ITFS`.

Question : how to create my array of interfaces for `MyModule` instanciation (taking into account the fact that elements have different parameters) ?

For example, I tried to use a generate statement :

```
module testbench()
...
generate
    genvar i;
    for (i = 0; i < NB_ITFS; i++)
    begin : interfaces
        itf #(.PARAM1(PARAM1_TABLE[i]), 
              .PARAM2(PARAM2_TABLE[i])) itf_inst (.clk(clk));
    end
endgenerate
...
endmodule
```

But in this case, the interface array is `interfaces[xxx].itf_inst` (and `.slave` if I want to select the "slave" modport) and the instanciation of `MyModule` using `interfaces[NB_ITFS].itf_inst.slave` raises an error.

I also tried without success:
 - a generic definition `itf itf_inst[NB_ITFS] (.clk(clk));` and tried to modify the parameters using `defparam` inside a generate block
 - "virtual interface" feature

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about putting your `generate` inside another interface:

```
interface itfa #(NB_ITFS = 4)(input logic clk);
  ...
  generate
    genvar i;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    begin : interfaces
      itf #(.PARAM1(i), 
            .PARAM2(i)) itf_inst (.clk(clk));
    end
  endgenerate
  ...
endinterface
```

and then using that as the interface to `MyModule`:

```
module MyModule #(NB_ITFS = 4)(itfa itfs);
  ...
endmodule
```

Then you can instanciate the outside interface (`itfa`) and connect it to an instance of `MyModule` in the usual way:

```
module testbench;
  ...
  logic clk;
  ...
  itfa #(4) itfa_inst (.clk(clk));
  ...
  MyModule #(4) MyModule0 (.itfs(itfa_inst));
  ...
endmodule
```

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/254C

Comment: Additionnaly, do you have any idea to still implement itf modports in itfa ? I would like to create a "slave" modport for itfa which is the array of itf_inst "slave" modports...